# Fast Report Null Data with SQL Challenge

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, report, fastreport

I want to send to SP (SQL) null data but fast reports convert null to zero and then send it. is there any tricks to send null for some parameters but Fast Reports convert it to zero and then send it.

```
Desirable Execute
exec MyStoreProcedure
    @MyParameter=NULL;

 But    

Fast Report Execute
exec MyStoreProcedure
    @MyParameter=0;
```

Update:

My code as follows:

```
try
        {
            using (FastReport.Report report = new FastReport.Report())
            {
                report.Load(txtFile.Text);
                report.ConvertNulls = false;
                report.SetParameterValue("LimitList", 0);
                report.SetParameterValue("InsuranceID", (int?)null);
                report.SetParameterValue("RegisterMonthNumber", null);
                report.SetParameterValue("RegisterYearNumber", null);
                report.SetParameterValue("FromDate", "2011-08-23 00:00:00");
                report.SetParameterValue("ToDate", "2019-10-02 00:00:00");
                report.SetParameterValue("SickName", null);
                report.SetParameterValue("SickNationalNo", null);
                report.SetParameterValue("SearchOnIsCloseYear", 0);
                report.SetParameterValue("NYear", 1398);
                report.SetParameterValue("NMonth", (int?)null);
                report.Show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: There is a setting `Convert Null Values` in report engine settings..this needs to be set to false.

Comment: https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=6351

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya where this option is available to set?

Comment: Please check the link I shared...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I dont know why you didnt help me? nothing changed with your comments !

Comment: I am not an expert on FastReport. The setting which I suggested I found from the documentation and forum of FastReport. I have not used it practically. Are you seeing all the null parameters value converted to 0 or only specific parameters are converted to 0?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to pass DBNull.Value?

```
    report.SetParameterValue("NMonth", System.DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: again @InsuranceID=0 passed

Comment: have you tried - report.SetParameterValue("InsuranceID", System.DBNull.Value); - ?

Comment: report.ConvertNulls = false;
                    
                    report.SetParameterValue("LimitList", 0);
                    report.SetParameterValue("InsuranceID", System.DBNull.Value);

Comment: is there any idea?

Comment: @M K - have you tried passing System.DBNull.Value instead of null for InsuranceID, RegisterMonthNumber etc ?

Comment: nothing changed. would you please check it with your pc?